# proof of this equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

How can I show the gradient of trace $(W^{T}MW)$ with respect to $W$ is equal to $MW+M^{T}W$.
where W is an $m\times n$ matrix and $M$ is an $m\times m$ matrix.
Can anyone help me in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you know various properties of such operations

$d$tr$(W^{T}MW)$ = $d$tr$(MWW^{T})$ = tr$(M(dW)W^{T})$ + tr$(MW(dW)^{T})$

=               tr$(W(dW)^{T}M^{T})$ + tr$(MW(dW)^{T})$

= tr$(M^{T}W(dW)^{T})$ + tr$(MW(dW)^{T})$

= tr$((MW\ +\ M^{T}W)(dW)^{T})$

hence $\frac{\partial tr(W^{T}MW) } {\partial W}$ = $MW\ +\ M^{T}W$

Comment: May I ask you why in result, trace has been removed (in last line when partial derivative has been applied)?

Comment: trace hasn't been removed...it's actually written in very small size due to latex compilation.

Comment: yes, but my mean is that why has been removed trace in final result (i.e. instead of ($tr(MW+M^{T}W)$))?!